# How do arrays created with malloc interact with cache?

Tags: c, caching, memory, malloc, vectorization

Let’s say I have now created a vector using code

```
double *a;
double b;
a = (double *)malloc(64*sizeof(double));

//Initialize a

for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
{
    b += a[i];
}
```

I guess when computing `b`, `a[i]` will be transported in cache separately for each `i`, am i right?

And what about creating `a` using `double a[64]` instead of `malloc`? Will the whole array be put into cache at the same time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there should be no difference, both stack and heap allocations consists of contiguous virtual address ranges.

Comment: "Will the whole array be put into cache at the same time?" Cache is normally filled based on memory accesses. It doesn't know anything about your arrays or the sizes of those arrays. No matter if you put it on the stack or on the heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And what about creating `a` using `double a[64]` instead of `malloc`? Will
> the whole array be put into cache at the same time?

If you use the `double a[64]` to declare, that should be put into the `Stack` at the same time.

If you use the `malloc` to assign memory, that should be put into the `Heap` at the same time.

Just the memory location is different.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/crrz7nT8s)

According to Demo,  the whole array shall be put into the `Heap` or `Stack` at the same time.

On the other hand, after `malloc` the `Size a` output `65` that reason is `malloc_usable_size(void* ptr)` problem.

(Using this function just want to make sure the memory whether already assigned.)

[`malloc_usable_size()` description](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_usable_size.3.html)

> The value returned by `malloc_usable_size()` may be greater than
> the requested size of the allocation because of alignment and
> minimum size constraints.  Although the excess bytes can be
> overwritten by the application without ill effects, this is not
> good programming practice: the number of excess bytes in an
> allocation depends on the underlying implementation.

> I guess when computing b, a[i] will be transported in cache separately
> for each i, am i right?

I not sure what your `cache` means, but `a[i]` should be taken from `Heap` or `Stack`.